# Uso de la variable local no asignada C# Ayuda

Tags: c#

Tengo un problema, soy muy novato y quiero crear una calculadora en C#, pero tengo este problema:

```
static long Suma(ref int x, int y)
    {
        int z;
        z = x + y;
        return z;
    }

    static long Resta(ref int x, int y)
    {
        int z;
        z = x - y;
        return z;
    }

    static long Multi(ref int x, int y)
    {
        int z;
        z = x + y;
        return z;
    }

    static long Divi(ref int x, int y)
    {
        int z;
        z = x + y;
        return z;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string op;

        int v1;
        int v2;
        int v3;

        int r1;
        int r2;
        Console.WriteLine("Hola! Inserta el primer valor");
        v1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Para una suma, toca '+' Para una resta, toca '-' Para una multiplicacion, toca '*' Para una division, toca '/'");
        op = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Dame el segundo valor");
        v2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (op.Equals("+"))
        {
            r1 = Convert.ToInt32(Suma(ref v1, v2));
            Console.WriteLine(r1);
        }
        v3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        r2 = v3 + r1;
        Console.WriteLine(r2);
```

Me dice que `r1` no esta asignado, pero `r1` esta asignado en el primer `if` (Obviamente asi no va a ser la calculadora, pero puse el `r2` y todo para probar porque no me funcionaba) En el `Console.WriteLine(r1)` Si me da el valor, entonces si esta asignado, no entiendo.

Comment: Es justamente por lo que mencionas, estas asignando r1 dentro de un if, por lo cual existe la posibilidad de que nunca llegue a ser asignado, ademas a pesar de que lo asignas en un if, luego lo ocupas para asignar el valor de r2, y si no pasaste por el if, estas usando la variable sin asignar. Por lo cual te reclama, puedes asignarle un valor de inicio como 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no te preocupes por ser novato, así empezamos todos. Acabo de revisar tu problema y una solución que te puedo dar es que le asignes un valor a tu variable r1, por ejemplo: r1 = 0; igualmente al momento de realizar el cálculo se reemplazará el valor. Te dejo el código de la funcion principal:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string op;

        int v1;
        int v2;
        int v3;

        int r1;
        int r2;

        r1 = 0; //Asignar valor a r1

        Console.WriteLine("Hola! Inserta el primer valor");
        v1 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Para una suma, toca '+' Para una resta, toca '-' Para una multiplicacion, toca '*' Para una division, toca '/'");
        op = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Dame el segundo valor");
        v2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        if (op.Equals("+"))
        {
            r1 = Convert.ToInt32(Suma(ref v1, v2));
            Console.WriteLine(r1);
        }
        v3 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        r2 = v3 + r1;
        Console.WriteLine(r2);
    }
```

Comment: Sos un genio, muchisimas gracias maestro